# How to add a few boxes, ajax windows on login form

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress 3.6 and the custom login plugin, which is great, however, I need to add some things to the login form, such as a language selector (which I have the

Any ideas on where to ad this onto the login box (wp-login.php) options of wordpress??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to go through the php file of the language selector plugin and figure out which function is called to perform the language change. You add this function along with some HTML if required to the part of the login page where you want the language option to appear.

Comment: I have the php function, just need to know where in the wp-login.php file I need to place, I have tried a few places but sometimes it doesnt show, sometimes it crashes the file

Comment: If you open wp-login.php you find the three form tags. Three forms are  used for login, registering and password retrieval. You can add the function some where in these form. Or look for the body tag or this `<div id="login">` tag and paste you function after this tag for the language function to appear neat the logo. Using fire fox you can see all the tags and place your function where you like.

Comment: it worked, this can be closed...
thanks Lafanter!! Great help!!

Comment: Mark it answered please. click the tick mark next to the answer.